# I created rating page, working properly in mozilla & chrome of desktop,laptops etc. but only issue in mobile views.. jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I created rating page, working properly in mozilla & chrome of desktop,laptops etc. but only issue in mobile views.. jquery not working properly..

When I click on rating in mobile view then its showing "Not rated" but its working fine in mozilla & chrome of desktop,laptop etc.

please suggest me changes in following code (for mobile view-checking with chrome)

My jquery code snippet:

```
<?php

        @ob_start();
        $p_id = base64_decode($_GET['p_id']);
        $u_id = base64_decode($_GET['u_id']);

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname="demo";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT `title` FROM `ci_table` where `p_id`='".$p_id."'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            }else{
              $row=array();
            }
        }    
        ?>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>Rating: </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/star-rating.css" media="all" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <style type="text/css">

               .registration{ width:600px; margin: 10px auto; background-color: #eaeaea; }
               .header {background-color: #00adee; padding: 20px;}
               .header img {margin: 0 auto;}
               .footer {background-color: ##CCC; border-top:solid 1px #CCC; padding: 20px;}
               .footer img {margin: 0 auto; width:50px}
               .rate{ width:100%; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden;}
               .rate img {margin: 0 auto; width:100%;}
               .rate h2{text-align: center;}
               .rate h4{text-align: center; margin: 20px auto}
               .rate .sunbtn{margin: 20px 35%; width:30%; background-color: 00adee;}
               .ratinggroup{margin:20px auto; width:350px}

            </style>
        <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="registration">
            <div class="header"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            <div class="rate">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><div class="row"><img src="images/hbg.png" class="img-responsive"></div></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12">

                <div class="row">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                    <h4>Rate This Item</h4>
                   <div class="ratinggroup">
                     <form id="addrate" name="addrate" method="post" action="add_rating.php#no-back">
                        <input name="prop_id" id="prop_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>">
                        <input name="user_id" id="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $u_id; ?>">
                        <input name="rat_val" id="rat_val" type="hidden" value="3">   
                        <input name="rates" id="rates" type="text" class="rating rating-loading" value="3" data-size="xs" title=""></div>
                        <div id="err" style="color: red; text-align: center; width: 100%"></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_rating" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info sunbtn">
                     </form> 

                </div>
                </div>
              </div>   
              </div>
             <div class="footer"> <img src="images/ftr-logo.png" class="img-responsive"></div>     
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready', function () {
                $('.kv-gly-star').rating({ 
                    containerClass: 'is-star'
                });


                $('.rating,.kv-gly-star').on(
                        'change', function () { 
                            console.log('Rating selected: ' + $(this).val());
                            var rt = $(this).val();
                            $('#rat_val').val(rt);
                });

                $('form#addrate').submit(function () { 
                      var rates = $('#rat_val').val();              
                      if(rates==""){
                          $('#err').html('Please rate the item');
                          return false;
                      }
                });

            });
        </script>
        </html>
        <?php $conn->close(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: What does _"not working properly"_ means? You need to explain what isn't working, what the expected result should be and what currently is happening.

Comment: Also, if it's your JS (jQuery) you're having issues with, why the PHP tag? PHP doesn't care what browser you're using since it's run in the back end.